# PostgreSQL data_directory doesn't match value set in postgresql.conf

Tags: postgresql, linux, ubuntu

I've recently updated from version 14 to 15 and I can't figure out why it's still using the data directory for 14.

I've verified that I'm using version 15.

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql -V
psql (PostgreSQL) 15.1 (Ubuntu 15.1-1.pgdg20.04+1)
```

However the data directory is still version 14.

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql -c "SHOW data_directory;"
       data_directory        
-----------------------------
 /var/lib/postgresql/14/main
(1 row)
```

I've verified that the data directory in `postgresql.conf` is correct.

```
$ sudo grep data_directory /etc/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.conf
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/15/main'
```

When I switch to the postgres user and check `/var/lib/postgresql/15/main` there is no `postgresql.conf` file.

How can I get postgres to use the correct data directory?

Edit:
I've just checked `sudo -u postgres psql -c "SHOW config_file;"` and it's set to `/etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf` so I will dig into that.

Comment: You have verified that your *client* version is v15.  You haven't verified the *server* version.  Newer client will connect to older server without complaint.

Comment: Under ubuntu by default, the config file is not stored in the data directory.  Of course '/var/lib/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.conf' doesn't (or shouldn't) exist, because you just demonstrated that it is called '/etc/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.conf' instead.